# Deployment slots on Azure WebApp

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

What exactly are deployment slots on Azure WebApp's? Are they separate websites on the same VM/IIS hosting the main webapp?

We currently use them and I understand what they do. Just want to understand what's behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Deployment slots are separate websites on the same VM that hosts your App service. That is why usage on one slot affects all other slots on the same app service as they are working under shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying Infrastructure layer of the App Service Plan is abstracted from documentation. But there's a simple trick to validate your understanding.

> Go to Advanced Tools from your WebApp Blade 
>    Kudu->Debug Console-> CMD

This opens up the command Prompt. Now Type `'hostname'`. You will now see the hostname of the machine running your webapp

Now try this on all WebApp Solots. You will notice that the machine name for all your WebApp Slots is the same as that of the WebApp itself.

This can logically conclude that the slots are part of the same machine as that of the WebApp